# Received SIGILL in random points in code (NDK)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I already got the answer so I'm just posting this in case any other coder as bad as me comes across this issue. (There is some black magic that someone might be able to explain though).

I am debugging native code in an Android device (Samsung Galaxy S7, although the problem will very probably reproduce in other devices) and the code will halt in random locations with a SIGILL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will show up when a function has been declared returning some value but it actually doesn't in its implementation, e.g.:

```
int myfunc() {
    someObject.performVeryImportantTask();
    // no return value! :(
}
```

I am now starting to appreciate the value of -Werror (I'd like to blame clang but I know better than that). What puzzles me is why it will throw a SIGILL in random points in code. My best guess is the lack of a return value at some point messes with the code and generates a jump to a non-valid address but if someone could enlighten me further please be my guest.

Comment: I'd recommend adding `-Werror -Wall` to your cflags. -Wreturn-type will catch these mistakes for you.